# PHP - регулярное выражение исключающее комментарии

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не могу корректно составить регулярное выражение для парсинга элементов, входящих в Си-шное перечисление.
Например, имеется перечисление вида:

```
typedef enum AG_TMP_MSG_ID
{
//single line comment
    /*multi-line
    comment*/
    TMP_ERR_SUCCESS = 0x00, //comment
        TMP_ERR_FAILURE = 0x01, //comment
    TMP_ERR_SETUP,// do not use TMP_ERR_SETTING
    TMP_MSG_NAME,/*TMP_PRODUCT*/
    TMP_MSG_NAME_1/*TMP_PRODUCT_1*/,
    TMP_MSG_NAME_BASE_MAX = TMP_ASD_OPTYPE_NAME_BASE + TMP_ASD_TRX_TYPE_END,
}
```

Из него необходимо получить только имена элементов перечисления. Все имена начинаются с префикса TMP_. 
Составил выражение вида,

```
(TMP_[\w]*)\w*
```

но оно хватает лишние имена (закомментированные, а также значения последнего элемента перечисления).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз у вас все элементы указаны в начале строк, то искать нужно от начала `^` каждой строки, потом пропускать имеющиеся в наличии пробелы `\s*\K` и забирать названия `TMP_\w+`:

```
/^\s*\KTMP_\w+/m
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/iCPV1C/1

Comment: Спасибо, но что, если библиотека регулярных выражений не поддерживает "\K" ?

Comment: Насколько древний у вас php? Обновляйте его до 7.x версии. А в регулярку можете группу ввести `/^\s*(TMP_\w+)/m`

Answer (score 2):

В таких случаях по хорошему нужен полный синтаксический анализ. Потому что есть много нюансов синтаксиса, которые надо обходить. Боле менее корректное регулярное выражение выглядит так (применять с флагом `s`):

```
(?>\/{2}.*?\n|\/\*.*?\*\/|=.*?[,}]|^.*?\{)(*SKIP)(*F)|TMP_\w*
```

Сначала мы сверх жадно захватываем все участки в которых анализ не должен проходить, т.е. содержимое комментариев двух видов, все от знака `=` до запятой или конца структуры, а так же, все до начала содержимого структуры (от начала текста до `{`). Все эти участки мы отбрасываем с помощью `(*SKIP)(*F)`, после чего наконец выделяем нужные подстроки с TMP.

Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mnnzQK/2) Демонстрация [работы в php](https://ideone.com/PI2vgH)

В случае если ваши регулярные выражения не поддерживают такой функционал, как SKIP, [можно обойтись без него](https://regex101.com/r/mnnzQK/3), но тогда будут пустые срабатывания, нашедшие пустоту. И надо будет брать только те элементы, где найденное вошло именно в первую группу захвата.

И вполне возможно, что я в данном выражении предусмотрел не все подводные камни и тогда надо будет его допиливать. На данный момент у меня нет уверенности правильной обработки вложенных разнотипных комментариев и последнего объявления в структуре при наличии после него комментариев.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал как-нибудь так, если брать именно описанные у вас казусы:

```
\n\s+(TMP_[\w\d_]*)\s?[=|,]
```

т.е. Это регулярка для случаев когда каждое объявлениен начинается с новой строки, после него идет возмжно один пробел, возможно сразу идет комментарий типа /*...*/(я кстати тут не учел комментарии после объявления но до запятой/равно начинающиеся с //), потмо идет или запятая или =. Если что-то еще может быть регулярка это не учтет.

Тестировать регулярки удобно тут:
https://regex101.com/